# TeamCity : How to define build and deployment steps for ETL and Autosys components

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, etl, autosys

I am working on continuous integration project to auto build and deploy ETL workflow and Autosys jil file to target environment.
We are using Perforce P4 for source code repository and Nexus for artefacts repository. Both ETL and Autosys applications are hosted on linux server.

- Developers extract workflow in the form of xml using Repository Manager from Informatica and check-in to source repository in Perforce.
- Developers extract jil file of Autosys job and check-in to source repository in Perforce.

**Requirement:**

As part of CI process, when developers check-in their code to source repository build process should get triggered and create artefacts of checked-in code and copy to artefacts repository.

Deployment process should get automatically trigger when it find any new artefacts and deploy artefact to target environment.

I would highly appreciate if someone helps me to know:

build and deployment steps

requirement of manifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding build/deployment steps its nothing more than:
open build configuration->build steps
create new step in e.g. following way:

Runner type: command line
step name: that_one_from_autosys
working directory: %system.autosys.home%
command executable: run_autosys_.bat

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [article](https://nprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/08/30/autosys-jobs-deployment-and-versioning/), I fully support the author.

1. You should have Jil templates and Environment contexts (+ other variables).
2. Than you need to have script that will generate Jil files for each Environment using templates and Env context.
3. Upload generated Jils to Artifact repository with sufficient version number.
4. Deploy Jil files using script that will operate with Autosys CLI commands. For instance, you need to stop running jobs, load BOXs before JOBs etc..